# SPSS data file : 6 GET DATA (2265) Unrecognized or invalid variable format

Tags: spss

I work currently on [SPSS export for LimeSurvey](https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/pull/815)

but with this file: https://framabin.org/?f7ceab1ae826c5a1#SgcIFGfnOsS6fdZ/OT9DzocrUSm44BStTU9MsTIs++Q=  user on SPSS (v25) receive 
`6 GET DATA (2265) Unrecognized or invalid variable format. The format is invalid. For numeric formats, the width or decimals value may be invalid.`

Some of variables :

```
 /TYPE=TXT
 /FILE='survey_832885_SPSS_data_file.dat'
 /DELCASE=LINE
 /DELIMITERS=","
 /QUALIFIER="'"
 /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
 /FIRSTCASE=1
 /IMPORTCASE=ALL
 /VARIABLES=
 V1 A100
 V10 F7
 V11 DATETIME23.2
 V13 A19
 V14 A16
 V17 A15
 V18 A255
 V19 F2
 V20 A1866
 V21 F2
 V22 A802
 V23 F1
 V24 F204
 V25 F1
 V26 A557
 V33 A664
 V34 F1
 V41 A783
 V42 F2
 V43 F2
 V44 F3.0
 V71 F63
 V72 A58
 V73 A522
 V74 A1485
 […]
```

Whole file on the bin. But i'm totally unsure of the fix to do ?

Looking difference with another one, there are the .0, but another spss user tell me it's OK for integer value …

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be here: `V24 F204`.
SPSS allows width of up to 40 for [numbers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/de/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_variables_numeric_variable_formats.htm).

Comment: OK, it's what i think. I don't see the if information about 40 digits. It's 40 digits or 40 caracter ( with . and -) ?